# Laplacian of Gaussian in openCV, how to find zero crossings?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

There is Laplacian function in openCV which directly calculate the double derivative. But this doesn't mean I will get the edges right? Because in the output there are many negative values.
I go through this link and realized that after that also I had to find zero-crossings. I don't get how to find zero crossings. Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 3):

A zero crossing will occur when

- a value equals 0, or
- two adjacent values have opposite signs

If you have something like

```
Laplacian(src, dst, CV_16S);
```

You just need to scan `dst` looking for those two cases

Comment: +1 - One minor note is that if you want to find the exact co-ordinates of where the zero-crossing is located, you will have to do some interpolation if you see that two adjacent values have opposite signs.   However, if you just want to find which pixels are edges, then detecting the opposite signs will totally be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy implementation in Python:

```
LoG = cv2.Laplacian(src, cv2.CV_16S)
minLoG = cv2.morphologyEx(LoG, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, np.ones((3,3)))
maxLoG = cv2.morphologyEx(LoG, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, np.ones((3,3)))
zeroCross = np.logical_or(np.logical_and(minLoG < 0,  LoG > 0), np.logical_and(maxLoG > 0, LoG < 0))
```

The whole idea is that ERODE operation computes the minimum on a neighborhood around each pixel, and DILATE the maximum. Hence, a zero-cross is defined in the case that a pixel with negative value has a positive value around, or a pixel with a positive value has a negative value around.

I hope it helps!!!

Comment: This is a godsend! To improve the edge detection task using the Laplacian of Gaussian approach, an additional [recommendation](https://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~elec539/Projects97/morphjrks/laplacian.html) is to use zero-crossings in regions of high local variance.